# SQL Join Issues: Third table's fields not displaying in Excel but in SQL

Tags: sql, join

This following script displays correctly in SQL, but as soon as you use From Other Sources in Excel 2010, the Detail_Desc field is empty.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT    
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".DealerCode,  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".Ratio_ID,  
  CUST_RatioID.Detail_Desc,  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".LineNr,  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".Dealer_RatioID,  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$"."201301",  
  COMP_DealerDetails.DlrCode  
FROM  
  COMP_CUST.dbo."CUST_1Mth_Composite$"  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$",  
  COMP_CUST.dbo.CUST_RatioID CUST_RatioID,
  COMP_CUST.dbo.COMP_DealerDetails COMP_DealerDetails  
WHERE  
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".DealerCode = COMP_DealerDetails.DlrCode
AND
  "CUST_1Mth_Composite$".Ratio_ID = CUST_RatioID.Ratio
```

Comment: What is the data type of that field ?

Comment: Not sure but can you try as, SELECT CAST(CUST_RatioID.Detail_Des AS varchar(8000)) AS Details_Des

Comment: That has solved it, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as,

```
SELECT CAST(CUST_RatioID.Detail_Des AS varchar(8000)) AS Details_Des
```

**Remarks** : Columns declared as VARCHAR(MAX) don't work well with Excel.

For the details about the problem  please go through this [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/467300/problem-with-varchar-max-via-sql-native-client)

Comment: Adding a sentence or two explaining why this works and what it does would make this a better answer for future searches.

Comment: Thanks #Mark for suggestion.